# Can i create local vuex for one difficult component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

vue2 question 
I have many difficult components with same struct

```
PersonCard
   components
     PersonForm
       components (many components)
       index.vue
     PersonImage
       components (many components)
       index.vue
   index.vue
```

i want to create vuex instance for one this component, not global.
at index.vue for PersonCard folder (root point of component) create vuex, and destroy if component destroy

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dynamic modules within your vuex instance. here is a link to read about this technique: [vuex dynamic module](https://medium.com/@arliber/vuex-next-steps-namespaces-and-dynamic-modules-92ea23a0ee9a)

but for example imagine you have a website with an admin panel and you don't need state management code to only be available in the admin panel so you can create a vuex store in a js file like:

```
// store/admin.js
export default {
  namespaces: true,

  modules: {},

  state: () => ({}),

  mutations: {},

  actions: {},

  getters: {},
};
```

then in the admin root page or component you import this file and do the following:

```
import adminStore from '@/store/admin;
...
beforeCreate() {
  const hasModule = this.$store.hasModule('admin'); // to make sure you don't register a module that already exists
  if (!hasModule) this.$store.registerModule('admin', adminStore);
},
beforeDestroy() {
  this.$store.unregisterModule('admin'); // removes the admin module when this component destroys
}
```

and as long as this component is not destroyed you have access to all the vuex functionality using [name spaced modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) like:

```
this.$store.dispatch('admin/someActionFromAdminModule')
```

[vuex doc for dynamic modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#dynamic-module-registration)

Comment: awesome thanks this is what I was looking for

Comment: glad I could help ;)